# How to get the git log without committing

Tags: git

How do i get the git log without committing to git? 
I'm trying to automate this and DON'T want the script to push back. I'm looking to get the git log after i clone.

I start by sending the command

```
git init
```

then i do

```
git clone url
```

This successfully clones the directory, now i want to do a git log but it doesn't let me. It gives me the error

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

According to the internet the solution to the issue is to commit but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me. 
Are there any commands i can use to get the git log for the URL I've just cloned WITHOUT having to push/commit to the repository?

Comment: The message seems pretty clear. There are no commits on the `master` branch so there is nothing for `git log` to show. What reasons do you have for expecting otherwise?

Comment: i do a git clone, then i run a batch file that does a build using the cloned code. If the build fails i would like to send an email out with the git commit that it failed on.

Comment: That's all completely doable and helps us understand the context for what you are doing. However, it still doesn't answer my question. Maybe I need to be more clear: does the repo that you are cloning have a branch named `master`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it does, i'm just working on the master branch currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what you are doing in some detail:

```
git init
```

This initializes the **current directory** as an empty git repository.

```
git clone url
```

This creates a **subfolder** and clones the remote repo into it.

```
git log
```

This shows a log of the repo created by `git init`. It doesn't show the log of the cloned repo like you expect **because that repo is in a subfolder**.

If you clone an existing repo, there is no reason to do `git init`. Instead do `git clone` and then `cd` to its subfolder For example, if you do `git clone https://example.com/foo.git`, it will create a folder named `foo` in your current directory. Before you do anything else you need to run `cd foo`. Then you can do `git log` just as you want.

Comment: I could be wrong but isn't git log supposed to show you the history of the git remote branch aka the main branch that is viewed through the URL?

Comment: @WorkerBee No, `git log` will show the commits of the current branch in your local repo. Immediately after `git clone`, that branch will be a copy of the branch from the remote.

Comment: @WorkerBee See my completely revamped answer for how to fix the real problem.

Comment: i have accepted your answer. I realized how bad of a question it is but i think i'll leave it on here in case someone else has a brain freeze. Or would you recommend that i delete it?

Comment: @WorkerBee Your question isn't bad at all. You clearly state the steps that you took and what happened when you did. You also give some idea of what you expect to be different. These are the three crucial components to a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Asi for log on the remote branch

```
git log origin/master
```

Or whatever remote/branch.

Comment: `git clone` will automatically checkout `origin/master` as the local `master`.

Comment: @Code-apprentice the branch that will be checked out will be whatever is checked out on the remote....it might be master  it might be something else. This way to call log gets that variable out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the case of the OP, this might have lead to more confusion...or perhaps gotten closer to the answer...because he would have gotten an error that branch origin/master doesn't exist.